# Conditional button appearance

Tags: php, session

I want a particular button to appear only when a user named 'admin' is logged into the site. My method is to examine the SESSION variable that contains the user name, check the value, and only have the button appear when the value is 'admin'. Here is the relative code snip. The issue I'm having is that the button appears all the time, so my code is not evaluating correctly. Or, I'm just totally on the wrong track.

```
 <div class="buttons"> 
                <a href="../index.html">Kip's Home Page</a> 
                <a href="rls-contentpop.php">See Member Area Content</a> 
                <a href="http://rlsforum.kipgarvey.com"target = "RLS Forum" rel="noopener noreferrer">RLS Forum/BB</a>
                <?php
                    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
         session_start(); //Start session
         }
        if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_USER_NAME']) && $_SESSION['SESS_USER_NAME'] == "admin") { 
                    ?><a href="rls-export2csv.php">View/Export Members List</a>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
```

Comment: `session_start` needs to be at the top of the page

Comment: ...unless you are using output buffering.